# Can't connect to Azure Postgres flexible server IP address not found

Tags: dns, azure-virtual-network, vnet, azure-postgresql, azure-private-dns-zone

I've created a Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible servers inside a virtual network, with a dedicated subnet for the database set to flexible servers. I've got a Private DNS Zone as well with an A record pointing to the database and a virtual network link setup. However, I can't connect to the database by the Azure Bash terminal.

I've tried using "host .postgres.database.azure.com" and I get this response:
[Error message from bash terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKxIT.png)

Has anyone encountered this before, or potentially knows how to solve this?

This has happened after following the default steps to create the private database in the vnet.

Answer (score 0):

I created Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible servers with virtual network like below:

[image]

> xxx.postgres.database.azure.com is an alias for xxx.privatelink.postgres.database.azure.com Host
> xxx.privatelink.postgres.database.azure.com not found : 3(NXDOMAIN)

This error usually occurs if the hostname for the database is not being resolved correctly. Check if you are using the correct hostname to connect to your server.

In private dns zone added A record and ensure that virtual network links is completed:

[image]

Now create linux virtual machine with same virtual network and Authentication type username and password and connect to hostname like below:

```
ssh hostname@ipadress
```

[image]

Now you need to install the postgresql-client tool to be able to connect to the server.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```

Connect to the server in your Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible servers under setting, connect and use that command connect from browser or locally like below:

[image]

```c
psql -h sql1.private.postgres.database.azure.com-p 5432 -U Imran123 postgres
```

```c
psql --host=mydemoserver-pg.postgres.database.azure.com --port=5432 --username=myadmin --dbname=postgres --set=sslmode=require
```

When I try to connect with the above command, got result successfully like below:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/inFylt3.png)]

Comment: This does work, although that's connecting via a VM in the same virtual machine. I appreciate this is an extension, but I didn't want to use a VM for connection to the database but was trying to do point-to-site using a virtual network gateway and Azure VPN Client. That's what got me into trying to work out why the host name wasn't resolving. Again, daft question but would you mind showing me how that could work?

(New to stackoverflow so if this breaks rules then please let me know).

Comment: i am stuck as hell as well, i mean i do not want another resource i am already on virtual network.  @sgw did you ever resolve this?